# Prevent Duplicate Child Records for Each Parent Record

Tags: trigger

I am have a custom object (VIP) with a master-detail to the Contact object.  The custom object has 1 picklist field (Type) and I want to make that field unique for each Contact/VIP record combination.  In other words the VIP records can have the same Type value as long as they are linked to different Contacts, but that value can only appear once for each Contact.

I've tried the code below, but it prevents me from entering any value in the type field.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious to do what I need.  Ideas?

```
trigger UpdateVIP on VIP__c (after insert, after update, after delete){
 
        Set<Id> contIds = new Set<ID>();
        
        if (Trigger.isDelete)
        {
            for(Type__c vip : Trigger.old){
                contIds.add(vip.Contact__c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(Type__c vip : Trigger.new){
                contIds.add(vip.Contact__c);
            }
        }

    Set<String> setVIPList = new Set<String>(); 
        for(VIP__c objVIP: [SELECT Contact__c, Type__c
                                 FROM VIP__c
                                 WHERE Contact__c in: contIds]){
            setVIPList.add(objVIP.Type__c);
            
            for(VIP__c objVIP2: Trigger.new){
                
                if(setVIPList.contains(objVIP2.Type__c))
                {
                    objVIP2.Type__c.addError('ThisType already exists for this Contact');
                }
                else
                { Rest of trigger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the duplicate rules of Salesforce, I'm not sure what are the limitation there, but 1 approach/trick that will work is:

1.Create unique field in the VIP object . Assume call it 'Contact_Type_Unique' . Make sure to mark the field as unique.

2.Create workflow/process buidler that populate this field with concatenation ContactId + Type.

This way anytime someone will try to create record that violate the duplicate he will get error. Drawback of the approach is that you cannot provide nice error message.

If you still prefer to use trigger, then it should be something like this:

/*
doesnt seems delete relevant...
{*/

```
map<Id, set<String>> contact_type_map = new map<Id, set<String>>();


if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isDelete)
    for(Type__c vip : Trigger.new){
        contact_type_map.put(vip.Contact__c, new set<String>());
    }
}


for(VIP__c objVIP: [SELECT Contact__c, Type__c
                         FROM VIP__c
                         WHERE Contact__c in: contact_type_map.keySet()]){
                         
    if(contact_type_map.get(objVIP.Contact__c).contains(objVIP.Type__c)){
        trigger.newMap.get(objVip.Id).addError('ThisType already exists for this Contact');
    }
    else{                    
        contact_type_map.get(objVIP.Contact__c).add(objVIP.Type__c);
    }
}
```

Just to clarify the above logic, the map value is set of types per each contact.

After the first vip record, map should look like

```
{
    'contactId1' => {'Type1'}
}
```

After second vip from different contact with different type it will be

```
{
    'contactId1' => {'Type1'},
    'contactId2' => {'Type2'}
}
```

After third vip record from the first contact it will be

```
{
    'contactId1' => {'Type1', 'Type2'},
    'contactId2' => {'Type2'}
}
```

Now, assume in the next iteration the vip is for contactId1 and with value Type1, then it should raise the error because the check
contact_type_map.get('contactId1').contains('Type1')
should return true.

Comment: Thanks. I can't use the WFR and unique field because there can be multiple non-unique child records. I already have a trigger firing on the custom object so I'd prefer that route. I tried your approach with the trigger but it did not prevent the duplicate record.

Comment: Debug it, and check where it stopped. Does it enter to the trigger at all? Does it find other VIP records correctly? If not, check why. Does it populate the map with the correct data? Add system.debug if needed

Comment: I did run some System.Debug statements. The map is populating the ID of the Contact record from the custom object, but I don't know if the IF condition looking for the VIP_Type  on all the VIP records related to the Contact is working as expected. Would I need a list of the VIP_Type records somewhere?

Comment: I modified the answer with examples of how the map might look like. You can try and print the map with system.debug inside the loop and check the data after each iteration

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do is check the new VIP record against any existing records for the associated Contact. Is that what the map will do or is it just checking new records?

Comment: It is checking against existing records. This is where it uses query to find all vip records for the relevant contacts. Not sure why it is not working for you. You will need to debug it to find the isuue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112610/discussion-between-j-neilan-and-liron-c).